# How to use Berkeley DB in an application without installing

Tags: python, berkeley-db, bsddb

I'm using Berkeley DB in a python project, and I am wondering if I can make the libraries available to python without specifically installing berkeley DB.

How can you embed Berkeley DB in an application generally?

Has anyone done this with python and bsddb3?

Comment: you want to use Berkeley DB without installing it???

Comment: Yeah, I should be able to just use the c/c++ libraries by keeping them with the application right?

Comment: When you compile pybsddb you can provide the option `--berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can't... at least not without installing something.  You'd have to statically link BDB into the python interpreter.  But, then you'd have a custom python binary you'd need to install.